# AlarmReceiver and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I wrote a class that extends BroadcastReceiver: 2 alarms every day should be started after boot completed but seems does not run. Many hours to check and but I don't understand where's the problem. If there a problem in the code?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION =
                           "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    final String not1[] = new String[11];
    int not1end = 10;
    int x;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, myIntent, 0);
            not1[0] = "one";
            not1[1] = "two";
            not1[2] = "three";
            // ...
            rando();
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher2;
            CharSequence tickerText = not1[x];
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notification=new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            CharSequence contentTitle = "title";
            CharSequence contentText = not1[x];
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05); // midday
            cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
            cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);// 8pm for example
            cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        }
    }

    private void rando() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int random = generator.nextInt(not1end);
        boolean flag = generator.nextBoolean();
        x = random;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
  <receiver 
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Did you add this receiver to your Manifest?

Comment: Try removing `android:exported="false"` and report back. Also `intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)` is WRONG. You must `BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())` as you will have NPEs soon

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive `BOOT_COMPLETE` events you need to add an Intent-Filter:

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Don't forget the appropriate permisson:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: same problem... I just updated the code (also see logcat there is not errors).

Comment: Hmm, I don't see where you launch the Notification or anything else. Add this line `Log.v("AlarmReceiver", intent.getAction());` as the first line in `onReceive()` and check your LogCat after booting the device.